# How can I install Ubuntu with command line from the USB iso to another partition

Tags: live-usb, live-cd, automation, ubiquity

My question differs from other thread from the fact that I want the installation to be done externally, from a workable system. I am looking for a command line utility `install-ubuntu-from-iso` that would directly install `Ubuntu` on a given partition  from the live USB `.iso`.

For instance

```
install-ubuntu-from-iso my_live_usb.iso /dev/sda1
```

would trigger an automatic Ubiquity installation and put the installed version on `/dev/sda1`

One way of doing it is to automatization the installation in a virtual boot.